# Adding value to array passed as an argument doesn't add value to it

Tags: arrays, bash, parameters

When I try to pass an array as parameter and add a value to it, it end's up as being empty at the end.

How would I add value to passed array? I would make the array global, but I will be passing different arrays, so it must be passed to this function as parameter.

```
#!/bin/bash

base='/home'

declare -a files_new
declare index

arrayit() {
    #$1 = path
    #$2 = array

    dir=($1/*)
    arr=$2

    for directory in "${dir[@]}"
    do
        if [[ -d $directory ]]
        then
            arrayit $directory $arr
        else
            arr[$index++]=$directory
        fi
    done
}

index=0
arrayit $base $files_new

for file in "${files_new[@]}"
do
    echo "File: $file"
done
```

Comment: I assume. But I'm not sure if I'm declaring it correctly inside function with `$2`.

Comment: `arr` is not an array; you are passing the first element (`$files_new` is equivalent to `${files_new[0]}`) as a regular string, and assigning that to `arr`.

Comment: Thanks chepner; Would passing `${files_new[@]}` be considered as passing entire array?

Comment: It would pass the *contents* of the array, not the array itself (meaning you wouldn't be able to modify the array from within the function).

Comment: If you are using `bash` 4, you can throw out `arrayit` altogether and just set `files_new=( "$base"/**/*/ )` to get a recursive list of directory names. (With `shopt -s globstar` to enable use of `**`.)

Comment: OMG, yes! Exactly what I needed but couldn't figure out the wildcard... I'm still interested in making OP script, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing around arrays in bash is a real PITA. I've found this is the most reliable method

```
$ ary=(foo bar baz)
$ fn() { local tmp="${1}[@]"; local copy=("${!tmp}"); declare -p copy; }
$ fn ary
declare -a copy='([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="baz")'
```

That gives you a **copy** in the function. Changes made in the function will not appear in the parent scope.

However, bash **version 4.3** has "name references"

```
$ fn() { 
    local -n myary=$1       # note: -n -- see "help declare"
    declare -p myary
    for key in "${!myary[@]}"; do printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "${myary[$key]}"; done
    myary[42]="new value"
}
$ fn ary
declare -n myary="ary"
0   foo
1   bar
2   baz
$ declare -p ary
declare -a ary='([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="baz" [42]="new value")'
```

Note the new value in the parent scope! Hooray!

Comment: Note that in both cases, I'm passing the **name** of the array to the function.